# how to pass value retrieved from jquery/javascript to child window via link using classic asp

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp-classic

i want to pass parent page's full url to child window via get method by click link to open child window (popup_postenq.asp).

please help me to solve this issue. my code is as below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var popup;
function ShowPopup(url) {
    if(popup)
    {
     popup.close();
    }
    popup = window.open(url, "self", "toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,location=no,statusbar=no,menubar=no,resizable=0,width=300,height=350,left = 0,top = 0");
        popup.focus();
  }
</script>

<%
dim urlloc
urlloc = "<p id='demo'></p>"
%>

<span style="color: #1686CC;"><a href="" onclick="ShowPopup('popup_postenq.asp?hh=<%=urlloc%>'); return false;" style="color: #1686CC;">send enquiry</a></span>

<script>
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 
window.location.href;
</script>
```

Comment: So why have you got `<p id='demo'></p>` in your `urlloc` variable? Also, you'll probably want to `Server.URLEncode` it.

Comment: @paul, thanks for your reply. as i m not good in jquery, please help me out how to do this? i want to pass "window.location.href;" value to another page which is child window via link.

Comment: So just pass it using JavaScript: `ShowPopup('popup_postenq.asp?hh=' + windows.location.href;);`

Comment: @Paul, thanks for your help but issue has been solved already.

Comment: Good job, really, as I've got one too many semi-colons in there!  ;o)